# Powershell CREDSSP and TLS 1.2

Tags: powershell, ssl, tls1.2, credssp

Server A is Server 2008 R2, Powershell V3 All SSL and TLS enabled and all Ciphers.
Server B is Server 2016, Powershell V5 and Only TlS 1.2 and specific set of Ciphers.

I cannot get Credssp authentication to work from A to B, even if I use

```
Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

i am aware this is a per Session setting so I included in the script itself.

If I set Server B (Server 2016) to turn on all SSL and TLS encryption, CREDSSP works no problem.

And yes i need to use CREDSSP because the script on Server B references a file share back on Server A.

Here is the script I am using, that again, works when all Version of TLS are enabled.

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -asplaintext -force
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "domain\user.service",$pass
#
#
# The Remote Execution Command. Fully Qualified Domain name is critical since we are using Credssp.
# Credssp is being used to resolve an issue with a double hop authentication issue. 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerB.domain.edu -command { C:\HelloWorld.ps1 } -Authentication Credssp  -Credential $mycred
```

The one thing I havent tried yet, but I am going to, is put both Server A and B on TLS 1.2 and see if it works that way. This is not a long term solution, because Server A cant be set to only TLS 1.2 at this time.

Comment: yeah actually i tried setting Server A to only support TLS 1.2 and i still get access denied. Only when I have TLS 1.0 Enabled on both servers am I able to get it to work.

Comment: the only ciphers that are enabled are TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_*

Comment: Try setting this value on the 2008 server and see if it works (it should've worked without this as a default, but some things are dumb. I ran into this issue) `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001`

Comment: As an added note, make sure you're applying patch KB3080079 for RDP TLS1.2 support and KB3099845 for .NET TLS1.2 support on the 2008 server.

Comment: yeah i checked and both of those are applied

Comment: Did you check x64/x86 keys have strongcrypto enabled?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171723/discussion-between-moore1emu-and-theincorrigible1).

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the issue was related to the Server 2008 only having The registry entries for the Server subkey of TLS and not the Client subkey of TLS on the SCHANNEL Reg setting. See picture

Once I added the Client Subkey and enabled TLS 1.2 Encryption, it finally started to work.

[image]